Showing the even numbers between two numbers which the user has entered
I've done it to be honest, but I feel like I'm writing extra code. I want a shortcut.
The code is:
let num1 = +prompt("enter a number");
let num2 = +prompt("enter a number");

if(isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2) || num1 == num2) {
    alert("Error!")
} else{
    let smallnum = 0, bignum = 0;
    if (num1 > num2){
        smallnum = num2;
        bignum= num1;
    } else{
        smallnum = num1;
        bignum = num2;
    }
    i = smallnum + 1;
    while(i < bignum){
        if (i % 2 == 1){
            i++;
            console.log(i);
        } else {
            console.log(i);
        }
        i += 2;
    }
}

Please tell me whether I've written well or not.


You can use max and min to get the lowest and highest number.

You can also use the check for even or not even only on the start.

If you wrap it in a function, you can end earlier and clean up the if
statement
 let num1 = +prompt("Enter a number");
 let num2 = +prompt("Enter another number");

 printEvenNumber(num1, num2);

 function printEvenNumber(num1, num2) {
     // Exit early
     if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2) || num1 === num2) {
         alert("Error!");
         return false;
     }
     // Use min and max
     let smallnum = Math.min(num1, num2);
     let bignum = Math.max(num1, num2);

     // Start from the next even number after smallnum
     let start = smallnum % 2 === 0 ? smallnum + 2 : smallnum + 1;

     for (let i = start; i < bignum; i += 2) {
         console.log(i);
     }
 }




If smallnum is even and bignum is the next even number, then the code will print out bignum which is not between the two numbers.
